# sql server join return only one row from second table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables, Vehicle and Reading.

**VEHICLE TABLE**

*VehicleId*  *Name*  *InitialReading*

1. ABC 584
2. XYZ 900

**READING TABLE**

*ReadingId* *Date* *Shift* *VehicleId* *Reading*

1. 2014-09-01 1 1 1234
2. 2014-09-01 2 1 2230
3. 2014-09-02 1 1 2500
4. 2014-09-02 2 1 3004
5. 2014-09-03 2 1 5000
6. 2014-09-03 1 1 4000
7. 2014-09-01 1 2 1000

Now I am having problem in combining the readings. I am searching the table for a `VehicleId`

for example, `VehicleId=1`, then the output has to be in the following format.

*`Date Shift OpeningReading ClosingReading`*

```
2014-09-01 1 584  1234 (if there are no opening for this date, I have to fetch the initial reading)   
2014-09-01 2 1234 2230    
2014-09-01 1 2230 2500
2014-09-01 2 2500 3004
2014-09-01 1 3004 4000
2014-09-01 2 4000 5000
```

I have tried this with CROSS APPLY

```
create table vehicle(vehicleId int identity(1,1),name varchar(25),initialReading int);
insert into vehicle values('ABC',584),('XYZ',900);


create table reading (readingId int identity(1,1),[date] date,vehicleId int,shiftId int,reading int);
insert into reading values ('2014-09-01',1,1,1234),('2014-09-01',1,2,2230), ('2014-09-02',1,1,2500),('2014-09-02',1,2,3004),('2014-09-03',1,2,5000),('2014-09-03',1,1,4000);
```

[SQLFiddle of the said experiment](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9f4c/1)

Comment: Can it be that your problem comes from teh cross apply?
http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql-2005/cross-apply-explained when I read that it seems to me that cross apply also (?optionally?) makes a group by which could explain why only 1 result is there (doing this as a comment instead of an answer as I'm unsure there)

Comment: As I said in the question, when we consider a date, I need the last entered reading just before that date as the opening reading. So the result will be wrong if I fetch more than a row.

Answer (score 0):

Already You Have Two table.. Now You Want combining two table where Vehicle id=1

just Use Sub Query

```
select R.Date R.Shift,(select V.Initial Reading From Vehicle V where v.Vehicle id =R.Vehicle Id) as Initial Reading , R.Reading as Closing Reading from Reading Where Vehicle id=@Vehicle id

or 

set @Vehicle id=1

select R.Date R.Shift,(select V.Initial Reading From Vehicle V where v.Vehicle id =R.Vehicle Id) as Initial Reading , R.Reading as Closing Reading from Reading Where Vehicle id=1
```

Comment: I am not combining two tables,  I am fetching the opening and closing reading from the same table. Please check the desired output. I am entering day and shift wise reading in same table. If there is no opening reading, ie for the first entry in the table I have to fetch the initial reading from vehicle table.